# TensorFlow - TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

when I try to run the following code:

```
def pixel_drop(image, drop_rate=0.5):
    img_h, img_w, _ = image.shape
    pixel_count = img_h * img_w
    drop_num = pixel_count * drop_rate

    for drop in range(int(drop_num)):
        rand_x = random.randint(0, img_h - 1)
        rand_y = random.randint(0, img_w - 1)
        image[rand_x, rand_y,:] = 0

    return image
```

I seem to get the following error:

> TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

It looks like I can't assign things to a tensor. How should I go about implementing this?

Comment: Is `image[rand_x, rand_y,:] = 0` the cause of the error ? Which line ?

Answer (score 1):

This [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/mrdbourke/tensorflow-deep-learning/blob/main/00_tensorflow_fundamentals.ipynb) has the details about how to `assign` values to different variables and constants.

This example `assigns` zeros of the appropriate shape to the tensor. But you may have a different type of variable in your code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def pixel_drop(image, drop_rate=0.5):
    img_h, img_w, _ = image.shape
    pixel_count = img_h * img_w
    drop_num = pixel_count * drop_rate

    for drop in range(int(drop_num)):
        rand_x = np.random.randint(0, img_h - 1)
        rand_y = np.random.randint(0, img_w - 1)
        image[rand_x, rand_y,:].assign(tf.zeros(shape=(3,)))

    return image

img_data = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform((100, 100, 3)))
print(pixel_drop(img_data))
```

Comment: Thanks! The notebook is really helpful. This pretty much solves it for me :)

Comment: So you may 'upvote' the answer.